# Dynamically Evaluate Regex Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I was hit with a predicament that I can't quite figure out. I am evaluating many large text strings containing large numbers of spaces between words. I have figured out the text to display properly I need to replace about half of the spaces in each segment with non breaking space characters. This varies if the number of spaces are even or odd. I have the replace boiled down to:

```
if (numberOfSpaces > 3) {
    double mathresult = (numberOfSpaces / 2);
    int numberNBSP = Math.Ceiling(mathresult);
    int numberSpace = Math.Floor(mathresult);
    string replaceText;
    for(numberNBSP > 0, numberNBSP--)
        replaceText+="&nbsp;";
    for(numberSpace > 0, numberSpace--)
        replaceText+=" ";
```

My issue now is calling this code for each instance of space segments. Each segment needs to be be evaluated individually and I feel like I have a blind spot in RegEx of how to do so. I hope this makes sense, thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Why force yourself to use RegEx? - IMHO this requirment doesn't seems to be easy with RegEx, though I must admit I didn't fully understand it.

Comment: `My issue now is calling this code for each instance of space segments.` -> so you are looking for `string[] arrayOfStrings = str.Split();` to get `segments` for each `whitespace` ?

Comment: I suppose RegEx may not be the best tool. One solution I thought of was going through the string one character at a time and stopping at each space, looking ahead to if there were still more spaces ahead, and then creating a segment from there and running this code. However, it seems awfully heady and inelegant.

Comment: I'm not totally following how to use str.Split() to create these segments. Even if I had an array of all of the segments, I would still need to replace the text at each spot in the greater string.

Comment: Something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ig4S3m - where the `if` condition could be what ever your heart desires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of passing a callback to `Replace` which will execute for every match that is made.

For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "I  hope    this makes   sense,   thank you   for    taking  the     time to   read   this!";
        Console.WriteLine("input:  " + input);
        Regex rx = new Regex(@" +");
        string output = rx.Replace(input, Evaluator);
        Console.WriteLine("output: " + output);
    }

    static string Evaluator(Match match)
    {
        string replaceText;
        int numberOfSpaces = match.Value.Length;          
        if (numberOfSpaces > 3) {   
            double mathresult = (numberOfSpaces / 2);
            int numberNBSP = (int) Math.Ceiling(mathresult);
            int numberSpace = (int) Math.Floor(mathresult);
            replaceText = "";
            for (; numberNBSP > 0; numberNBSP--) replaceText += "&nbsp;";
            for (; numberSpace > 0; numberSpace--) replaceText += " ";
        } else {
            replaceText = match.Value;
        }     
        return replaceText;       
    }
}
```

Obviously, the logic of replacing the spaces is your own, and I didn't look into that.

Alternatively, you could use the regex string `" {4,}"` which matches 4 or more space characters, then you could get rid of the `if (numberOfSpaces > 3)` test etc.

If you want to be able to match all whitespace, such as tabs and newlines, then use `\s` rather than a single space character.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thank you for the solution! I didn't know how (or even if it was possible) to send each match to a function but this eloquently solves the wall I've been hitting! Have a good one!